# Dynamic layout in Web App with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've had a MVC 4 / Entity web project dropped into my lap, and I've never used either before. I'm getting through it but the simple things are really tripping me up - Like hiding or displaying a link in my layout based on a parameter in the database.

I created a function in my HomeController that simply sets 2 bools in the ViewBag for whether or not a person is a manager or superuser. I call that function using

```
@Html.Action("SetupViewBag", "Home")
```

which sits right after the `<body>` tag in my layout. Here is the code for SetupViewBag:

```
public void SetupViewBag()
{
   ViewBag.IsManager = ADAccess.IsManager(SessionManager.GetUserName());
   ViewBag.IsSuper = SessionManager.SuperUser();
}
```

The bools are set properly and in the right order when I set up break points, but when I try to access them using the below code, I get a 'Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type.'

```
@{
   if((bool)@ViewBag.IsManager){                       
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Management", "Management", "Home",null, new { id = "managementLink" })</li>
   }                     
}
```

There has to be something really simple I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say "bools are set properly" you mean you have `ViewBag.IsManager=true` (or false) in your code? And that you do not have it inside an if-else that would make it null on the view?

Comment: Updated question with the SetupViewBag code. When I set a break point inside SetupViewBag and on the if((bool)@ViewBag.IsManager){ line, the ViewBag.IsManager is set before it is referenced. However, it is referenced in the layout file, not a view per-se, which I believe to be my problem after ongoing research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, @Dakine83, you should setup your ViewBag on the controller constructor method like so:

```
public class YourController : BaseController {
    public YourController(){

    }
}
```

The reason for that is because the Layout page is already rendered the time your action method has been called. The reason you have a null `ViewBag.IsManager`.

UPDATE: Use a base controller

```
public class BaseController : Controller {
    public BaseController() {
            ViewBag.IsManager = ADAccess.IsManager(SessionManager.GetUserName());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Is the only option to have the exact same function on each of my 8 controllers? That seems ridiculous, but not surprising.

Comment: No, you can have, and I suggest "should have", a base controller. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this might work for you,please try it once
  @Html.ActionLink("Management", "Management", "Home", new { id = false }, null);

Thanks

Comment: The link works just fine - it's the check to see if the link should be displayed that is breaking.

Comment: I get a 'Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type
i think you have mention above issue, and it will be resolved if you set new { id = true/false }
as the parameter in the actin methos is of bool type.

Comment: The 'cannot convert' is not coming from that line. That line works as expected without the if around it.